# Keyboard shortcut or command to qualify a type name instead of import?

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, rider, jetbrains-rider

Rider gives us the option to import a type name if it is currently not in scope. But is there a way to make it qualify the name instead?

[image]

I don't necessarily want to import if it's just for a single type. It'll be easier to qualify the name with it's namespace and go from there but it doesn't seem to be an option. Visual Studio, Code, and other IDEs has this as an option, does Rider have it too?

Answer (score 2):

There is a YouTrack issue about it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-494279.
As a workaround, it is possible to force full type name qualification on import for particular types:
[image]

**File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import** for Windows and Linux or **JetBrains Rider | Settings or Preferences | Editor | General | Auto Import** for macOS.

Comment: Thanks Mary. I'm not using Rider at the moment but I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: This screenshot is from Rider: "File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import" for Windows and Linux or "JetBrains Rider | Settings or Preferences | Editor | General | Auto Import" for macOS.

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding this kind of information directly to it